# how to set grid view with name and image in swiftui

Tags: ios, json, swiftui

my code results two grid views of images and keys. I want to list like image and its name in single grid .what I want to do? I want to set second forEach as my Text in my code and I want to pass the text as my navigation bar title in the next view.[I want the result like this from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItSFP.png)

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
        struct ProductTypes: Identifiable {
            let id: Int
            let image: String
        }
       // @State var type = ProductTypes.self
        let typeImages = [ProductTypes(id: 1, image: "bakery"),ProductTypes(id: 2, image: "diary"),ProductTypes(id: 3, image: "fruits"),ProductTypes(id: 4, image: "vegans"),ProductTypes(id: 5, image: "vegetables")]
        
        @ObservedObject var groceryViewModel : ProductViewModel
        
        let columns : [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()),count: 3)
        var body: some View {
           // let keys = groceryViewModel.prodType.map{$0.key}
            
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView{
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns,spacing: 12) {
                       
                            ForEach(typeImages) { image in
                                VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 4){
                                    Spacer()
                                    Image(image.image)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                        .scaledToFill()
                                        .frame(width:
                                                100,height: 100)
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                            ForEach(groceryViewModel.prodType.keys.sorted(),id: \.self) { item in
                                NavigationLink(destination: ProductListView(groceryViewModel: ProductViewModel()), label:{
                                    Text(item)
                                    .font(.system(.headline,weight: .bold))
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                })
                         }
                    }
                    
                    
                    .onAppear {
                        groceryViewModel.readJSONFile(filename: "Groceries")
                    }
                   /* .onTapGesture {
                        let values = groceryViewModel.prodType.values
                    }*/
                    
                    
                }
                
                
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Categories"),displayMode: .inline)
            }
           
            
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View{
            ContentView( groceryViewModel: ProductViewModel())
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Dictionary.init(groupingBy:_:)`, or juste use `filter()` on `productData` array?

Comment: Your question is not clear. In the code you show, 
`productData` is an array of `struct ProductData` objects. It is not an array 
of `dictionaries` as you mention in your question, and there is no `specific key as key and model as value`. So where are the `dictionaries` that you want to group?

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 

In particular, show the code for your `homeview` with the `grid`, and how you navigate and pass the data to the `productlistview`.